# What's the right HTTP Status code for a blocked, abusive user?

Tags: http, http-status-code-403, http-status

I am building an app in which users might be blocked for using offensive language. When a user is blocked, his or her app can not access some API calls.

What should be the right [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) when a blocked user tried access these API parts? [Error 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) seems like a good choice, but I wonder if there's anything more specific.

Comment: @user4419802 Made my day. Care to fetch some coffee please?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific code for *4xx You have used too many swear words*. Don't overthink it. If the user is **forbidden** to do something, use 403. If you want to be funny, use 418.

Comment: @AdamMatan Error 418: I'm a _tea_ pot.

Comment: The answer to *"is there's anything more specific"* is No.  It is up to you what to send.  (Nobody who matters should care about your choice in this context.)

Comment: @StephenC True. That was my choice back then. Write that as an answer and I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for completeness ....

The answer to the question is that there is no other code that is (clearly) more appropriate than 403.  As Wikipedia says:

> "HTTP 403 is returned when the client is not permitted access to the resource despite providing authentication - either because authentication failed, **or for some reason besides authentication**, such as insufficient permissions of the authenticated account. This other reason needs to be acted upon before re-requesting access to the resource."

That is a good fit to the scenario you describe.

The other thing is that since you have blocked the users, you probably don't care what *they* think about the "correctness" of the status code.  Nobody else will care one way or the other.

Ultimately it is your choice.